# Does CALayer retain CGColor objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, calayer

I have a UIView for which I would like to set its borderColor:

```
UIView *myView = ...;
myView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

Is it safe to do it like this?
The UIColor object will be autoreleased and with it the CGColor object. Now, does the borderColor property retain the CGColor so that it is safe to let the UIColor be autoreleased, or do I have to retain the UIColor in a separate instance variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CGColor` is not an object in the same sense as `UIColor`, but the layer would retain it using `CGColorRetain()` so this is fine

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since the layer needs the color to exist so that it can function, it retains it.

Although I agree that the docs or the @property declaration should declare this intent.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was confused. Thanks!